# Build-timeout Plugin in Jenkins: how long is 'too long'?

Tags: jenkins, build-automation, jenkins-plugins

I would like to take advantage of this plug-in but the 'Abort the build if it's stuck' option doesn't set any timer and the description of the plug-in doesn't say how long is the timer, it just says: 'This plugin allows you to automatically abort a build if it's taking too long'

My question is how long is that? 1 hour, less/more?
Can I set up my own time?
Is that timer for the overall job or every line in the batch file has that timer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just upgraded to Jenkins 1535 and with that a new upgrade of the plug-in was available.  That upgrade fixed the problem I was having.  The timeout time is now available.

Answer (score 11):

Build-timeout plugin has multiple options (taken from help documentation of [Build Timeout Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build-timeout+Plugin))

> - Absolute time. Use this if you know exactly how much time your build should  not exceed in advance
> - Elastic time. Use this option if you want Jenkins to decide on the time. It basically averages out on the last n builds and will stop a
>     build if it exceeds given percentage. If you do not know in advance
>     how much time your build takes, use this option
> - Likely Stuck. Use Jenkins' Executor.html#isLikelyStuck() heuristics based approach to detect build is suspiciously taking for a long time

In your case, option two seems to be best initially.

Comment: I can't see this option :(

Comment: You need to restart your Jenkins server after  you have installed the plugin. Without restart,  you will not see all the options.

Comment: I did.  I am running version (Jenkins ver. 1.534) and I can't see it.
On version 1.532 they reported a problem.  Maybe it is there in 34 as well. Are you running the latest version?

Comment: No, I have an older version, 1.528

Answer (score 2):

I upgraded my jenkins installations recently to 1532 and noticed on jobs that the radio to set time has gone missing. I may file this as a bug.

This is what it should look like on your jobs:

https://github.com/jenkinsci/build-timeout-plugin/pull/14#issuecomment-24114825

Comment: Thanks a lot for thsi snapshot.  The previous answer didn't make sense to me as I was never able to see the radio button for the time.  I only installed this plug in on the latest version of jenkins

Comment: BTW, I am using 1534.  Still the option is not available for me.